# React Native Collapse list with button

Tags: react-native, button, key

I'm making an app with expo react native, and I made a collapse that shows profile information about all users on my SQLite database.
I added a button (touchableopacity) inside the collapse and my idea is to edit information in the input where I'm showing information, but i don't know how to link the button press to the profile where is being touched.

so my code is as follows (i deleted styles to make it cleaner to see):

```
render(){
    
    
    const miLista = this.state.datos.map((item) =>   //this is "list" and it works(show information of each profile and shows the button of each profile when i open the collapse of each on of them)
              <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <Collapse>
                  <CollapseHeader>
                    
                      <Text>{item.id} {item.nombre}</Text>  //here shows id and name (from sqlite data)
                  
                  </CollapseHeader>
                  <CollapseBody >
                    <View key={item.id} >
                      <Text >Nombre</Text>
                      <TextInput 
                        value={item.nombre}
                        
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ nombre: val})}/>
                    
                      <Text style=>Rut</Text>
                      <TextInput 
                        value={item.rutPersona}
                       
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ rutPersona: val})}/>
                    
                      <Text >Clave</Text>
                      <TextInput 
                        value={item.clave}
                       
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ clave: val})}/>
                     
                      {this.boton(item.id)}
                    </View> 
                  </CollapseBody>
                
                  
                </Collapse>
              </ScrollView>
  
      
    );
    

    return(
        
      <View >
        <SafeAreaView >
            <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
              <FontAwesome5  name="bars" size={24} color="#161924"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Perfiles</Text>
        
        <ScrollView>
          {miLista}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate on the issue you are having, I can't understand what are you trying to ask.
are you asking how to go to the profile screen with a click of a button or you are asking how to edit certain data with a click of a button?

Comment: Hello, i needed to edit data on a collapse list.

Answer (score 0):

so i needed to add .bind to the onpress of my button and pass the data: like this
boton(id,nombre,rutPersona,clave){

```
return(
  <TouchableOpacity 
    key={id}
    style={styles.boton}
    onPress={this.funcionBoton.bind(this,nombre,rutPersona,clave,id)}
    >
    <Text>SAVE </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

};